# How will my distro be affected when transitioning to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I'm currently using Ubuntu GNOME 16.10, and I'll soon be upgrading it to 17.04. After that, I'll switch to 17.10. I've made a lot of customisations to my desktop. My question is, how will it be affected when I switch to 17.10? Will my customisations stay intact, or will I have to start over from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your customizations should stay intact unless there is a drastic change in desktop. (for example KDE going from plasma 4 to plasma 5)

third party applications may be removed if dependencies can not be satisfied with the updated software. the distribution upgrader will tell you what it is going to remove, read the list carefully. if you have the repos for the software enabled it will try to update the software if dependencies can be met

I recommend the following commands before doing the upgrade to be sure you have the newest packages for your current version:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then upgrade to the newest version

Comment: The command `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` doesn't work as expected under Ubuntu GNOME 17.04, i.e.  starting an upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sadi -- unless you change your repos, those commands update your current version; which should be done before upgrading. Ubuntu's prefered upgrade method is `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Thanks, I entered the 3rd command after completing the first 2, but it seems I need to enter `sudo do-release-upgrade` as the 4th step...